# Ajuda Require Node

Tags: javascript, html, json, node.js

Tudo começa quando eu tento receber um JSON pela API do CNPJ, estou utilizando node e consequentemente o NPM e assim utilizando o AXIOS para receber o JSON. Ok, tudo certo até ai. Entretanto desejo pegar as informações do json e atribuir a campos do formulário (mesmo formulário que recebo o CNPJ). E me deparei com o seguinte problema, para utilizar o AXIOS necessito realizar um require para o carregamento do módulo, entretanto não consigo fazer isso dentro de um arquivo .js carregado pelo browser, alguém pode me ajudar em como consertar isso ou sugerir outro modo de chegar ao meu objetivo ?

```
Html

   <label for="cnpj"><div >CNPJ: </div></label>
   <input name="cnpj" id="cnpj" type="text" onblur="getCnpj(this.value)">

   <label for="endereco"><div >Endereco: </div></label>
   <input placeholder="Digite o endereço" id="endereco" type="text">

   <script type="text/javascript" src="../js/cnpj.js"></script>
```

```
Javascript

const getCnpj = (cnpj) => {
    const axios = require('axios');
    axios.get('https://www.receitaws.com.br/v1/cnpj/'+cnpj)
    .then(function (response) {
        if (response.data.status == "ERROR")
            alert("CNPJ Inexistente");
        else{
          document.getElementById('endereco').value = response.data.endereco;
        }    

    })
    .catch(function (error) {
        console.log(error);
        alert("Erro ao buscar por Cnpj");
    });
}
```

Comment: Alguma resposta ajudou a resolver o problema e pode sanar dúvidas similares de outros usuários? Caso positivo não esqueça de marcar a resposta como aceita. Pra fazer isso é só clicar no ✓ do lado esquerdo da mesma (abaixo do indicador de up e down votes).

Answer (score 0):

O `Node` é um contexto diferente da sua página cliente. O `require` por si só funciona apenas no `Node`. Para utilizar no cliente você só precisa importar o `axios` no seu `HTML`:

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/axios/0.18.0/axios.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Vale detalhar que nesse caso ele não irá usar o require.

Comment: @ColdMeson_06 não acho necessário. `require` no `node`, são contextos diferentes

Answer (score 0):

Isso é uma questão de build system, o que você quer fazer é "compilar" o seu código JS antes de rodá-lo no browser, no seu caso o [browserify](http://browserify.org/) deve ser o suficiente já que requer praticamente 0 configuração, mas vale dar uma olhada no [Babel](https://babeljs.io/) também, porém configurar Babel já é um topico por sí só...